# how to display dateTime to GMT format in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this dateTime 2006-08-30T15:08:46.000-04:00. how to display like this 30th Aug 2006 at 19:08 GMT. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 1.0 or an XSLT 2.0 processor? Only XSLT 2.0 has support for a dateTime data type and for formatting values of that type: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date.

Answer (score 3):

```
format-dateTime(
  adjust-dateTime($x, xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H')), 
  "[D1o] [MNn,*-3] [Y0001] at [H01]:[m01] GMT")
```

assuming you are on XSLT 2.0.