# How do I convert DateTime to another format?

Tags: javascript, xml, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

From a weather feed I'm getting the data for dates in the form of `2012-05-17`.

How do I convert that to `Thursday May 17th` form?

Comment: You certainly can't do that with XML alone. Which language will you be using?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10315163/1221319

Comment: You probably could with XSLT, if you really needed to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse date string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-date-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I am using (as a beginner) XSLT fragments with dreamweaver.

Comment: Questions about parsing and formatting datetime have been asked dozens of times on SO. Pick up a similar question, browse through answers and improvise if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Parse the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-date-string-in-javascript) into a JavaScript `Date` object.
2. [Format the Date](http://phrogz.net/js/FormatDateTime_JS.txt) object however you like.

*See also: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse) and [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date) questions.*

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var originalDateTime = '2012-05-17',
splitedDatetime = originalDateTime.split('0'),
date = new Date(),
date.setFullYear(splitedDatetime[0],splitedDatetime[1]-1,splitedDatetime[2]),
formatedDateString = date.toLocaleFormat("%A %B %d");
```